# RuntimeError: libpng signaled error while visualizing cnn layers

Tags: matplotlib, keras

I am visualizing layers of cnn with keras. The visualization is on mnist test image.[The model summary is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bidmb.png)
The code for visualization is as follows:

```
layer_names = []
for layer in model.layers[:12]:
    layer_names.append(layer.name) # Names of the layers, so you can have them as part of your plot

images_per_row = 16

for layer_name, layer_activation in zip(layer_names, activations): # Displays the feature maps
    n_features = layer_activation.shape[-1] # Number of features in the feature map
    size = layer_activation.shape[1] #The feature map has shape (1, size, size, n_features).
    n_cols = n_features // images_per_row # Tiles the activation channels in this matrix
    display_grid = np.zeros((size * n_cols, images_per_row * size))
    for col in range(n_cols): # Tiles each filter into a big horizontal grid
        for row in range(images_per_row):
            channel_image = layer_activation[0,
                                         :, :,
                                         col * images_per_row + row]
            channel_image -= channel_image.mean() # Post-processes the feature to make it visually palatable
            channel_image /= channel_image.std()
            channel_image *= 64
            channel_image += 128
            channel_image = np.clip(channel_image, 0, 255).astype('uint8')
            display_grid[col * size : (col + 1) * size, # Displays the grid
                     row * size : (row + 1) * size] = channel_image
    scale = 1. / size
    plt.figure(figsize=(scale * display_grid.shape[1],
                    scale * display_grid.shape[0]))
    plt.title(layer_name)
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(display_grid, aspect='auto', cmap='viridis')
```

This code visualize output of first two layers and show image with filters. But with the third layer it throws the error as follows:

```
RuntimeError: libpng signaled error

<Figure size 1152x0 with 1 Axes>
```

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall matplotlib but still it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a logic error:

```
<Figure size 1152x0 with 1 Axes>
```

implies that `scale * display_grid.shape[0] == 0` which can only happen if you set `n_cols` to zero in this line:

```
n_cols = n_features // images_per_row
```

caused by `n_features` being < `images_per_row/2`.

There should be a nicer error [in future versions of matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13857).